# Avoid "filesort" on UNION RESULT

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, filesort

Sub-query 1:

```
SELECT * from big_table
where category = 'fruits' and name = 'apple'
order by yyyymmdd desc
```

Explain:

```
table       |   key           |   extra
big_table   |   name_yyyymmdd |   using where
```

Looks great!

Sub-query 2:

```
SELECT * from big_table
where category = 'fruits' and (taste = 'sweet' or wildcard = '*')
order by yyyymmdd desc
```

Explain:

```
table       |   key               |   extra
big_table   |   category_yyyymmdd |   using where
```

Looks great!

Now if I combine those with UNION:

```
SELECT * from big_table
where category = 'fruits' and name = 'apple'

UNION

SELECT * from big_table
where category = 'fruits' and (taste = 'sweet' or wildcard = '*')

Order by yyyymmdd desc
```

Explain:

```
table       |   key      |   extra
big_table   |   name     |   using index condition, using where
big_table   |   category |   using index condition
UNION RESULT|   NULL     |   using temporary; using filesort
```

Not so good, it uses filesort.

This is a trimmed down version of a more complexed query, here are some facts about the big_table:

- big_table has 10M + rows
- There are 5 unique "category"s
- There are 5 unique "taste"s
- There are about 10,000 unique "name"s
- There are about 10,000 unique "yyyymmdd"s
- I have created single index on each of those fields, plus composite idx such as `yyyymmdd_category_taste_name` but Mysql is not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM big_table
    WHERE category = 'fruits'
      AND (  name = 'apple'
          OR taste = 'sweet'
          OR wildcard = '*' )
    ORDER BY yyyymmdd DESC
```

And have `INDEX(catgory)` or some index *starting* with `category`.  However, if more than about 20% of the table is `category = 'fruits'` will probably decide to ignore the index and simply do a table scan.  (Since you say there are only 5 categories, I suspect the optimizer will rightly eschew the index.)

Or this *might* be beneficial:  `INDEX(category, yyyymmdd)`, in *this* order.

The `UNION` had to do a sort (either in memory on disk, it is not clear) because it was unable to fetch the rows in the desired order.

A composite index `INDEX(yyyymmdd, ...)` might be used to avoid the 'filesort', but it won't use any columns after `yyyymmdd`.

When constructing a composite index, *start* with any `WHERE` columns compared '='.  After that you can add one range or `group by` or `order by`.  [More details](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

`UNION` is often a good choice for avoiding a slow `OR`, but in this case it would need three indexes

```
INDEX(category, name)
INDEX(category, taste)
INDEX(category, wildcard)
```

and adding yyyymmdd would not help unless you add a `LIMIT`.

And the query would be:

```
( SELECT * FROM big_table WHERE category = 'fruits' AND name = 'apple' )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT * FROM big_table WHERE category = 'fruits' AND taste = 'sweet' )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT * FROM big_table WHERE category = 'fruits' AND wildcard = '*' )
ORDER BY yyyymmdd DESC
```

Adding a limit would be even messier.  First tack `yyyymmdd` on the *end* of each of the three composite indexes, then

```
( SELECT ... ORDER BY yyyymmdd DESC LIMIT 10 )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... ORDER BY yyyymmdd DESC LIMIT 10 )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... ORDER BY yyyymmdd DESC LIMIT 10 )
ORDER BY yyyymmdd DESC  LIMIT 10
```

Adding an OFFSET would be even worse.

Two other techniques -- "covering" index and "lazy lookup" might help, but I doubt it.

Yet another technique is to put all the words in the same column and use a `FULLTEXT` index.  But this may be problematical for several reasons.

Comment: One more thing...  "filesort" is not the evil; the complexity of the query is.

Answer (score 0):

This must be also work without UNION

```
SELECT * from big_table
where 
    ( category = 'fruits' and name = 'apple' )
    OR
    ( category = 'fruits' and (taste = 'sweet' or wildcard = '*')
ORDER BY yyyymmdd desc;
```

Comment: My query was without UNION in the first place, however for some reason, it took too long to find matching rows in the 2nd condition (wildcard).

Comment: Please post us the full EXPLAIN of your QUERY. It is possible that there is no INDEX (COMPOSITE) with the field taste or wildcard